# Over the probability of answering in a random way to given questions.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, recreational-mathematics

Let's suppose there is a test of $N$ questions, each one with multiple choices answer, let's say $p$. To say if better, for every question there are $p$ possible answers, but **one and only one** is the correct one.

What is the probability to get a good score by answering them in a random way? (good score = at least $70-80$ %).

I also would like to generalise it, by introducing $N_i$ questions, in which each of them has a different number of multiple choice answer $p_i$, in which

- Case 1: one and only one is the correct one;
- Case 2: there could be one or 2 correct answers (not always $2$).

To be clear: $p_i$ represents the number of given answers, not the number of possible correct answers.

How could I proceed?

I thought that for the first question, in which we have $N$ questions with $p$ possible answers each one, we can safely state that there is one and only one way in which we can get $100$ %. So I have $\frac{1}{p}$ probability to answer correctly to the first question, $\frac{1}{p}$ for the second and so on.

The moral is: I have $$\frac{1}{p^N}$$

probability of answering good to all the question. That seems legit. But what if I ask for a total score of $80$ % ?

About the second case, I guess the same reasoning holds, namely: $\frac{1}{p_1}$, $\frac{1}{p_2}$ and so on.. hence:

$$P = \prod_{k = 1}^N\frac{1}{p_i}$$

And if I have the possibility of having two correct answers, I shall introduce a sort of bias $b_i$ such that

$$b_i = \begin{cases} 1 \\ 2 \end{cases}$$

Depending on the question. Example: if the second question has $4$ possible answers but only $2$ of them are correct, then I'll have $1/2$ probability in guessing them correctly.

This suggests me the probability for each question is

$$P_i = \frac{b_i}{p_i}$$

So the total probability should be:

$$P = \prod_{i = 1}^N \left(\frac{b_i}{p_i}\right)$$

Does that hold? Or it's a load of malarkey?

And how could I manage to get the desired result of $80$ %?

Comment: Maybe the binomial distribution could help you.

Comment: $(2x/p - (p-2)/p)^{N_2}(x/p - (p-1)/p)^{N_1}$ - the product of two powers then sum all coefficients with exponent higher than 80% of $N_1+N_2$ or what your threshold was.

Comment: Suppose there are 20 questions, each with 5 possible answers (of which one is chosen at random by a clueless student). Let $X$ be the number of correct answers. Now 75% of 20 is 15, so you want $P(X \ge 15).$ Then $X \sim Binom(20, .5)$. In R, `1 - pbinom(14, 20, .5)` returns 0.02069473, so it seems random guessing is not the recommended route to academic excellence. It seems to me that the case with different numbers of choices for different problems needs to be specified in more detail. I know of no particular named distribution for this, and would probably use simulation for a solution.